# How do I get rid of this weird pattern on my mesh?

Tags: modeling

I imported a mesh from roblox studio into blender and weird shadow patterns appeared on it.[image]

Comment: Did you try to recalculate the normals?

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing 'custom split normals' in the object data panel

Answer (score 0):

The weird pattern on the mesh is most likely something to due with roblox. Try re-importing the model and messing with the lighting.