# Imported model from Roblox Studio has weird textures

Tags: text-object

I tried importing a model from Roblox Studio, but the textures look weird. The model has these weird lines on it.

[image]

Comment: Maybe https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128153/how-do-i-get-rid-of-this-weird-pattern-on-my-mesh ?

Comment: what lines are you talking about? i dont see anything wrong. it looks nice. u should mark or encircle the areas that you are refering to.